# What's with the review queues?

Tags: support, review-queue

Have the review queues changed or have I messed up my settings somehow?

If they have changed it's not an improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the company is working on [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/295232) since a few weeks. That post has been [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) in the sidebar widget on the homepage

[image]

which is one way to keep track of (upcoming) changes to the network. They welcome constructive feedback in the form of answers/comments, and many community members have already done so. Please have a look, perhaps your concerns have already been addressed.

Comment: Thanks, I won't get involved, so long as it's not my fault I don't much care what they do.

Comment: They have long ago declared that they see themselves as benevolent dictators, so I won't get involved either.